# React ref giving ReferenceError

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I am trying to get reference to a DOM element using the `ref` attribute React provides:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  popup;
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.renderTemplate()}</div>
    )
  } 
  renderTemplate = () => {
    if(someCondition) {
      return(
        <span ref={(pop) => {this.popup = pop}}></span>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

`this.popup` is undefined in above code when the app runs. On debugging it in Chrome Dev Tools, I see

> **"ReferenceError:** pop is not defined at eval (eval at render fileName.js:lineNo:columnNo)".

Why is this happening?

Comment: where is this popup coming from ? if its coming from other component it should be `const { popup } = this.props  `or`this.props.popup` ?

Comment: `popup` is a member of the `A` class. It is used to store reference to the span element. This reference is required elsewhere in the app. And the error is not regarding `popup`,  it is regarding `pop`

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't throw this error. Are you using `pop` anywhere else?

Comment: @FelixKling: No, `pop` is not used anywhere else. Just used to store reference in `popup`.

Comment: @FelixKling: But I am passing `popup` as a prop to a child component.

Comment: "No, pop is not used anywhere else" - I don't believe you :).

Comment: A ReferenceError usually means that you are trying to access a variable that wasn't declared. `pop` is clearly declared as a parameter of the function, so that line wouldn't cause that error.

Comment: @FelixKling: Strangely, `<span ref={(pop) => {this.popup = pop; console.log(this.popup}}></span>` correctly logs the span element in console, but passing `this.popup` to a component just after `span' results in `undefined` being passed. Also, if I pause execution at `span', hovering over `pop' and `this.popup` shows ReferenceError.

Comment: Just to make things more clear, I am getting error "ReferenceError: pop is not defined at eval (eval at render fileName.js:line:column)". Here 'FileName' is basically the compiled output file produced by webpack and has es5 code.

Comment: And what does the compiled code look like?

Comment: @FelixKling: Here is the compiled code: `return _react2.default.createElement('span',{ref: function ref(pop): {_this5.popup = pop;} }`

Comment: "_But I am passing popup as a prop to a child component_" can you show how you pass it down and what you are doing with it inside the component that receives it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to bind `popup` to `this` somewhere in the component as well as adding a return keyword inside `returnTemplate`

```
  renderTemplate = () => {
      if(someCondition) {
        return <span ref={(pop) => {this.popup = pop}}></span>
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made the corrections in my question. `return` is already present in my code, I just forgot to include it in my question here. Binding of popup to `this` is not required. This is ES6/7 syntax.

Comment: @dk49: FWIW, *class fields* are an experimental feature (ES.next). It's not part of any released version yet.

Comment: @FelixKling: I am using babel for transpiling my code to es5, so this is not an issue.

Comment: @dk49: I know it’s not. I’m just saying that it’s not “ES6/7 syntax”.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try writing `renderTemplate` as a method of the class and not a function assigned to a property ?

```
  renderTemplate(){
    if(someCondition) {
      return(
        <span ref={(pop) => {this.popup = pop}}></span>
      )
    }
  }
```

There you will have the reference to `this`.

Comment: The problem is not with `this`. `pop` is not getting assigned to `this.popup`. If I initialise `popup` with a value, `this.popup` correctly shows that value inside `renderTemplate`.